# OpenERP 7.0: Why does product.product inherit from product.template?

Tags: inheritance, openerp-7

What advantage is gained by having `product.product` inherit from `product.template` instead of defining all the fields directly in `product.product`?

```
_name = "product.product"
_description = "Product"
_inherits = {'product.template': 'product_tmpl_id'}
```

When would I use this technique in new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `_inherits` you will do a kind of polymorphic model in the database way.

For example `product.product` inherits `product.template` or `res.users` inherits `res.partner`. This mean we create a model that gets the know how of a `Model` but adds aditional data/columns in a new database table. So when you create a user, all partner data is stored in `res_partner` table (and a partner is created) and all user related info is stored in `res_users` table.

To do this we use a dict: `_inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}` The key corresponds to the base model and the value to the foreign key to the base model.

From here you can mix inheritance if you dare...

here some links:

http://help.openerp.com/question/46/the-different-openerp-model-inheritance-mechanisms-whats-the-difference-between-them-and-when-should-they-be-used/

https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/object_inherits/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its really helpful